# Is it possible to update service with a bound application

Tags: cloud-foundry

Is it possible for an app bound to a service to update this service? Or is it something only an admin Cf can do ?

For instance, I would like to execute the following command

```
cf update-service test_db -c '{​​​​​"data":{"serviceStopped":true}}'
```

What I have in mind: create an app bound to test_db to update the value of the dictionnary.

Comment: Can you expand on your question? What do you mean by "update the service"? Are you trying to change something specific within a service you're using? Are you trying to modify credentials? or something else?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I edited my question. Please let me know if it's unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible for an app bound to a service to update this service? Or is it something only an admin Cf can do ?

Yes, but it requires credentials. The application on CF itself has no permissions, so you would need to supply the credentials of a user or client that has permissions that the application can use to update the service.

Any user or client that is in the same org and space as the service with the SpaceDev role will have access to update the service.

If you want to have an application make calls to the Cloud Controller, like to update a database, you can do that by embedding the cf CLI and invoking it, you can use a library like the [cf-java-client](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client), or you can [use the REST API](http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/) directly.

Comment: But in this case, binding the app to the service is of no use ? Since I'm using the SAP CF, the password has to be changed twice a year. I was looking for a solution without maintenance...

Comment: The credentials that are passed to your app through the binding are credentials to use the service itself. In order to make a change through the CF API, you need credentials for the CF API. They are different. You could create a user-provided service and pass in credentials for the CF API to your app, but it would need to be a separate service that you create.